# Renaming all png files except one in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to rename all of my png files except one. For example all png files except one named `DontChangeMyName.png`

So far I have this code of line that works pretty much how I want it, except it renames all png, and I would like to exclude it from renaming `DontChangeMyName.png`

```
Dir -filter *.png| %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("Picture{0}.png" -f $nr++)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use below code to accomplish your requirement.

```
Dir -filter *.png|% -Process{if($_.Name -ne "DontChangeMyName.png"){Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("Picture{0}.png" -f $nr++)}}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

As `Rename-Item` accepts piped input - more *PowerShellish* is:

```
Get-Childitem -Filter *.png | 
  Where-Object Name -ne DontChangeMyName.png |
    Rename-Item -NewName {("Picture{0}.png" -f $script:nr++)} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`

Or use gci's `-Exclude` parameter

```
Get-Childitem -Filter *.png -Exclude 'DontChangeMyName.png' |
    Rename-Item -NewName {("Picture{0}.png" -f $script:nr++)} -WhatIf
```